# Use a directive in another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I create directive for SVG icon. now i want use this icon directive in the another directive.

**Icon directive:**

```
<icon p="shopping-add"></icon>
```

**I want something like this:**

```
app.directive("product", function() {
  return {
      restrict : "E",
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope:{
        ngModel:"="
      },
      template : '<div><icon p="iconName"></icon></div>'
  };
});
```

How i can create nested directive?

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```js
var app = angular
  .module('MyApp', [
  ])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 

}])
.directive("product", function() {
  return {
      restrict : "E",
      template : '<div><icon image="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-s85bDKtYHLk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAVI/SSfL19tTusw/photo.jpg?sz=32"></icon></div>'
  };
})
.directive("icon", function() {
  return {
      restrict : "AE",
      scope :{
        image:'@'
      },
      template : '<img src="{{image}}" />'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div class="main-content" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="Main as myCtrl">
      <div>
           <product ></product>
     </div>
</div>
```